# SuiteScript Workflow Action error SSS_USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED and email not attaching to related records

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am receiving the following error when I try to process more than approx 15 transactions:

```
Error: SSS_USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED","message":"Script Execution Usage Limit Exceeded","stack":["createError(N/error)","onAction(/SuiteScripts/sdf_ignore/Send Remittance PFA Workflow Action.js:84)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"SSS_USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED","details":"Script Execution Usage Limit Exceeded","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["createError(N/error)","onAction(/SuiteScripts/sdf_ignore/Send Remittance PFA Workflow Action.js:84)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}
```

The script is a workflow action script that is triggered when the user clicks on a button to send email remittance advice.

This works for the most part unless I exceed a certain number of transactions.

Do I need to use another script type?
Or can I modify the following script to reduce its governance usage?

```js
    /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
     */
    define([
      "N/search",
      "N/record",
      "N/render",
      "N/file",
      "N/xml",
      "N/email",
    ], function (search, record, render, file, xml, email) {
      function onAction(context) {
        var fileObj = [];
        var record = context.newRecord;
        log.debug("record", record);
        var batchId = record.getValue({ fieldId: "name" });
        var id = record.id;
        log.debug("recordid", record.id);
    
        var vendorpaymentSearchObj = search.create({
          type: "vendorpayment",
          filters: [
            ["type", "anyof", "VendPymt"],
            "AND",
            ["custbody_9997_pfa_record", "anyof", id],
          ],
          columns: [
            search.createColumn({
              name: "transactionnumber",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "Transaction Number",
            }),
            search.createColumn({
              name: "formulatext",
              summary: "GROUP",
              formula: "{entity}",
              label: "Vendor",
            }),
            search.createColumn({
              name: "formulatext",
              summary: "GROUP",
              formula:
                "CASE WHEN {vendor.custentity_2663_email_address_notif} IS NULL THEN {vendor.email} ELSE  {vendor.custentity_2663_email_address_notif} END",
              label: "Email",
            }),
            search.createColumn({
              name: "total",
              summary: "SUM",
              label: "Amount (Transaction Total)",
            }),
            search.createColumn({
              name: "currency",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "Currency",
            }),
            search.createColumn({
              name: "trandate",
              summary: "GROUP",
              sort: search.Sort.ASC,
              label: "Date",
            }),
    
            search.createColumn({
              name: "internalid",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "internalid",
            }),
            search.createColumn({
              name: "internalid",
              join: "vendor",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "Internal ID",
            }),
            search.createColumn({
              name: "internalid",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "Internal ID",
            }),
          ],
        });
        var searchResultCount = vendorpaymentSearchObj.runPaged().count;
        log.debug("vendorpaymentSearchObj result count", searchResultCount);
        vendorpaymentSearchObj.run().each(function (result) {
          var emailAddress = result.getValue(result.columns[2]);
          var transactionNumber = result.getValue(result.columns[0]);
          var amount = result.getValue(result.columns[3]);
          var date = result.getValue(result.columns[5]);
          var vendor = result.getValue(result.columns[1]);
          var resultId = result.getValue(result.columns[6]);
          var vendorId = result.getValue(result.columns[7]);
          var transactionId = result.getValue(result.columns[8]);
          log.debug(
            "emailAddress: ",
            emailAddress +
              " transaction bumber: " +
              transactionNumber +
              " amount: " +
              amount +
              " date: " +
              date +
              " vendor: " +
              vendor +
              " resultId " +
              resultId +
              " transactionId " +
              transactionId
          );
          var pdfFile = render.transaction({
            entityId: parseInt(resultId),
            printMode: render.PrintMode.PDF,
            formId: 109,
            inCustLocale: true,
          });
          pdfFile.folder = 1351;
          var fileId = pdfFile.save();
    
          var pdffile2 = file.load({ id: fileId });
          //   var fileObj = file.load({ id: parseInt(fileId) });
    
          var mergeResult = render.mergeEmail({
            templateId: 8,
    
            //   entity: {
            //     type: "employee",
            //     id: parseInt(recipient),
            //   },
    
            entity: {
              type: "vendor",
              id: parseInt(vendorId),
            },
    
            recipient: {
              type: "vendor",
              id: parseInt(vendorId),
            },
            supportCaseId: null,
            transactionId: parseInt(resultId),
            customRecord: null,
            // {
            //     type: "customrecord_2663_entity_bank_details",
            //     id: parseInt(bankDetailsId),
            // },
          });
          var emailSubject = mergeResult.subject;
          var emailBody = mergeResult.body;
          //create a placeholder in the original HTML with an element called NLID. This will replace that with a value that is part of the script
          emailSubject = emailSubject.replace("NLVENDOR", vendor);
          //   emailBody = emailBody.replace("NLDOCNUMBER", bankDetailsId);
          var emailString = JSON.stringify(emailAddress);
          email.send({
            author: -5,
            //   recipients: 2020,
            recipients: emailAddress,
    
            subject: emailSubject,
            body: emailBody,
            attachments: [pdffile2],
            relatedRecords: {
              entity: parseInt(vendorId),
              customRecord: {
                id: parseInt(id),
                recordType: 'customrecord_2663_file_admin', //an integer value
              },
       //     transactionId: 38326,
            },
          });
    
          return true;
        });
    
        /*
         vendorpaymentSearchObj.id="customsearch1658554258593";
         vendorpaymentSearchObj.title="Bill Payments in a Payment Batch (copy)";
         var newSearchId = vendorpaymentSearchObj.save();
         */
      }
      return {
        onAction: onAction,
      };
    });
```

Another issue I am having with this script is the email.send method doesn't throw an error for the custom record but doesn't actually attach the email messages to the stated transaction type either. It doesn't allow me to attach the emails to a transaction at all (I get an 'unexpected error' if I do)

I finally got a map reduce working for this:

```js
    /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType MapReduceScript
     */
    define([
      "N/search",
      "N/record",
      "N/render",
      "N/file",
      "N/xml",
      "N/email",
      "N/runtime",
    ], function (search, record, render, file, xml, email, runtime) {
      function getInputData(context) {
        var scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript();
        var recordId = scriptObj.getParameter("custscript_recordid");
        // var record = context.newRecord;
        // log.debug("record", record);
        // var batchId = record.getValue({ fieldId: "name" });
        var id = recordId;
        log.debug("recordid", recordId);
    
        var vendorpaymentSearchObj = search.create({
          type: "vendorpayment",
          filters: [
            ["type", "anyof", "VendPymt"],
            "AND",
            ["custbody_9997_pfa_record", "anyof", id],
          ],
          columns: [
            //0
            search.createColumn({
              name: "transactionnumber",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "Transaction Number",
            }),
            //1
            search.createColumn({
              name: "formulatext",
              summary: "GROUP",
              formula: "{entity}",
              label: "Vendor",
            }),
            //2
            search.createColumn({
              name: "formulatext",
              summary: "GROUP",
              formula:
                "CASE WHEN {vendor.custentity_2663_email_address_notif} IS NULL THEN {vendor.email} ELSE  {vendor.custentity_2663_email_address_notif} END",
              label: "Email",
            }),
            //3
            search.createColumn({
              name: "total",
              summary: "SUM",
              label: "Amount (Transaction Total)",
            }),
            //4
            search.createColumn({
              name: "currency",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "Currency",
            }),
            //5
            search.createColumn({
              name: "trandate",
              summary: "GROUP",
              sort: search.Sort.ASC,
              label: "Date",
            }),
    
            //6
            search.createColumn({
              name: "internalid",
              join: "vendor",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "vendorId",
            }),
            //7
            search.createColumn({
              name: "internalid",
              summary: "GROUP",
              label: "searchResultId",
            }),
          ],
        });
        log.debug(
          "vendorpaymentSearchObj result count",
          vendorpaymentSearchObj.runPaged().count
        );
    
        var vendorPayments = [];
    
        vendorpaymentSearchObj.run().each(function (result) {
          vendorPayments.push({
            emailAddress: result.getValue(result.columns[2]),
            transactionNumber: result.getValue(result.columns[0]),
            amount: result.getValue(result.columns[3]),
            date: result.getValue(result.columns[5]),
            vendor: result.getValue(result.columns[1]),
            resultId: result.getValue(result.columns[7]),
            vendorId: result.getValue(result.columns[6]),
            id: id,
            // transactionId: result.getValue(result.columns[8]),
          });
          return true;
        });
    
        return vendorPayments;
      }
      /**
       * @param {MapReduceContext.map} context
       */
      function map(context) {
        try {
          log.debug("context", context);
          const result = JSON.parse(context.value);
          log.debug("result", result);
          var emailAddress = result.emailAddress;
          var transactionNumber = result.transactionNumber;
          var amount = result.amount;
          var date = result.date;
          var vendor = result.vendor;
          var resultId = result.resultId;
          var vendorId = result.vendorId;
          var id = result.id;
          // var transactionId = result.transactionId;
          log.debug(
            "emailAddress: ",
            emailAddress +
              " transaction bumber: " +
              transactionNumber +
              " amount: " +
              amount +
              " date: " +
              date +
              " vendor: " +
              vendor +
              " resultId " +
              resultId +
              // " transactionId " +
              // transactionId +
              "vendorId " +
              vendorId
          );
          // for (var i = 0; i < context.value.length; i++) {
          var pdfFile = render.transaction({
            entityId: parseInt(resultId),
            printMode: render.PrintMode.PDF,
            formId: 109,
          });
    
          pdfFile.folder = 1351;
          var fileId = pdfFile.save();
    
          var pdffile2 = file.load({ id: fileId });
          // context.write({
          //   key: context.value[i],
          //   value: [
          //     [pdffile2],
          //     pdfFile,
          //     fileId,
          //     emailAddress,
          //     transactionNumber,
          //     amount,
          //     date,
          //     vendor,
          //     resultId,
          //     vendorId,
          //     transactionId,
          //   ],
          // });
    
          log.debug("fileid: " + fileId + pdfFile + pdffile2);
          context.write({
            key: resultId,
            value: JSON.stringify({
              vendorId: vendorId,
              vendor: vendor,
              fileId: fileId,
              emailAddress: emailAddress,
              id: id,
            }),
          });
          // }
        } catch (ex) {
          log.error("Error on map", ex.message + ex.error);
        }
      }
    
      //   var fileObj = file.load({ id: parseInt(fileId) });
      /**
       * @param {MapReduceContext.reduce} context
       */
      function reduce(context) {
        try {
          var reduceResults = context.values; //note: context.values and not context.value unlike the earlier stages. Also, this is not JSON.Parse
          log.debug("reduceResults", reduceResults);
          var pdffile2 = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < reduceResults.length; i++) {
            //note: this is context.value(S)
            log.debug("vendorId", JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).vendorId);
            log.debug("key", context.key);
            if (reduceResults) {
              var mergeResult = render.mergeEmail({
                templateId: 8,
    
                //   entity: {
                //     type: "employee",
                //     id: parseInt(recipient),
                //   },
    
                entity: {
                  type: "vendor",
                  id: parseInt(JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).vendorId),
                },
    
                recipient: {
                  type: "vendor",
                  id: parseInt(JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).vendorId),
                },
                supportCaseId: null,
                transactionId: parseInt(context.key),
                customRecord: null,
              });
    
              log.debug("mergeResult", mergeResult);
              var emailSubject = mergeResult.subject;
              var emailBody = mergeResult.body;
    
              log.debug("email body", emailBody);
              var pdf = file.load({
                id: JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).fileId,
              });
              var vendorName = JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).vendor;
              log.debug("vendorname", vendorName);
              pdffile2.push(pdf);
              //create a placeholder in the original HTML with an element called NLVENDOR. This will replace that with a value that is part of the script
              var emailSubjectNew = emailSubject.replace("NLVENDOR", vendorName);
              log.debug("email subject", emailSubjectNew);
              var emailString = JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).emailAddress;
              log.debug("emailstring", emailString);
              email.send({
                author: -5,
                recipients: JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).emailAddress,
                subject: emailSubjectNew,
                body: emailBody,
                attachments: pdffile2,
                relatedRecords: {
                  entity: parseInt(JSON.parse(reduceResults[i]).vendorId),
                  transactionId: parseInt(context.key),
                },
              });
            }
          }
        } catch (ex) {
          log.error("Error on reduce", ex.message + "" + ex.name);
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * @param {MapReduceContext.summarize} context
       */
      function summarize(summary) {
        log.debug("context", summary);
        summary.output.iterator().each(function (key, value) {
          contents += key + " " + value + "\n";
          return true;
        });
      }
      return {
        getInputData: getInputData,
        map: map,
        reduce: reduce,
        summarize: summarize,
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To me this operation seems more suitable for a Map/Reduce if you don't know how many results the search will have. Meaning if it always rendered one PDF and sent it so no need for a MR but if the amount is unknown so a Map/Reduce is the way to go.

If you still want to try and reduce usage on this script you can try:

- Not saving and loading the PDF. Instead just generate it and send it. (assuming this is not a requirement)
- You can try adding search criteria to narrow down the query

I'm doubtful that either of these will reduce the usage enough to make a real difference. I would look into the N/task module.

Comment: Thank you Nadav. I have attempted to go the map reduce route.
My initial reluctance for this was that I couldn't quite work out how to write a map reduce script (I am very new to writing script)

I have followed along with tutorials though am a bit stuck distinguishing what goes into the map stage and what goes into the reduce stage

I will post the amended script once I have that working

Comment: Hey, it seems you figured it out. Just a few tips for next time ;)

1) you can literally return the search itself: return search.create({ ... }) and then you will get the search results in the map stage.
2) The map stage is used for "grouping data". You pass data from the Map to the reduce stage using a key and the reduce will run once for each unique key that was passed. 
3) Remember there are no real rules. The thing to remember is that each time a stage is triggered it has ITS OWN usage limit so spreading the usage evenly across the stages is important.

Comment: Thanks so much Nadav for the advice and help :)